# GAE thread pool inconsistently slow

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, threadpool, java-7

I'm setting up a service on Google App Engine. I need the service to make five external service calls, combine their results, and return the combined answer. The external service is out of my control.

I set up a thread pool like this:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

// ...

Executor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3,
    10,
    30,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(50),
    ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory());
    // I looked into the backgroundThreadFactory(), but that would only
    // work with a backend service, which is deprecated.

// ...

Collection<Result> doWork(List<Task> tasks) {
  final ResultCollector collector = new ResultCollector(); // My own class to join results.
  final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(tasks.size());
  for (Task task : tasks) { // My own worker class
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        task.execute(collector); // Does work, populates collector.
        latch.countDown();
      }
    });
  }

  latch.await();
  return collector.getResult();
}
```

Then my service calls started timing out from time to time. I put in some logging and discovered that in some cases the `Runnable`'s `run()` call wasn't getting called for ten or more seconds. I'm not sure if this is because App Engine is creating a new thread pool for each request. As I said in the comments, I can't use a `backgroundThreadFactory`, because it's not a backend instance.

Is there a more performant way to make these sorts of calls in parallel in App Engine?